# Connect/disconnect operations inside another thread

Tags: android

I defined `connection` variable in top of the main class:

```
private XMPPConnection connection;
```

I am connecting to server with following code:

```
public void connect(final String username,final String password) {
    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig=new ConnectionConfiguration("server ip", 5222,"localhost");
            XMPPConnection connection=new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);
            try{
                connection.connect();
            }catch(XMPPException ex) {
                setConnection(null);
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                connection.login(username,password);
            } catch (SaslException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            setConnection(connection);
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

You see I am using thread for this operation.And if connection was successful `setConnection` method is calling.

`setConnection` method:

```
public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
        this.connection=connection;

        if (connection != null) {
        //Other stuff
        ....
```

So,I am setting `connection` variable inside thread.But when I want to disconnect from server i am getting crash report.

**Disconnect code:**

```
        try{
            connection.disconnect();
        }catch (SmackException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Report:

```
01-27 14:14:05.162: E/XMPPConnection(3160): Error in listener while closing connection
01-27 14:14:05.162: E/XMPPConnection(3160): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-27 14:14:05.162: E/XMPPConnection(3160):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
01-27 14:14:05.162: E/XMPPConnection(3160):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-27 14:14:05.162: E/XMPPConnection(3160):     at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:365)
01-27 14:14:05.162: E/XMPPConnection(3160):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.socks5.Socks5Proxy.<init>(Socks5Proxy.java:108)
```

I know this error.Android doesn't allow to use network operations from ui thread.But I already set connection inside another thread.Why do i need one more thread for disconnect operation ?

I followed this tutorial:http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000119

And in this tutorial they didn't use another thread for disconnect.Why I am getting this error ?

Comment: are you gettng that in which version of android ?

Comment: I am getting that in kitkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using you code which you have posted. define strict mode thread policy permission in onCreate method of Activity or Application

Assuming you have given INTERNET permission in manifest

```
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

If you dont wants to use the code which you have posted thn alternate solutions for that below i hve mentioned

Use Async task for the Network related operation or long process related

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

```
    XMPPConnection connection;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public void connect(final String username, final String password) {

        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                "server ip", 5222, "localhost");
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);
        try {
            connection.connect();
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            setConnection(null);
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            connection.login(username, password);
        } catch (SaslException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private class XMPPConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            connect(username, password);
            return null;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();


        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
           //  from here update the ui and make ui related changes once
            // onpostExecute is called
             setConnection(connection);

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
        username = "username@chat.abc.com";
        password = "1234567";
        new XMPPConnection().execute();

    }
}
```

also Please check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)

For async and ui changes , network related operation on main thread related please check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#Avoiding)
and make sure `setConnection(XMPPConnection connection)` you are not doing any UI update related things..

OR you can also try

```
 XMPPTCPConnection connection;

            @Override
            protected void onResume() {
                    super.onResume();
                    connect(LOGGED_USERNAME,"pass");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPause() {
                    super.onPause();
                    try{
                       connection.disconnect();
                    }catch (SmackException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

     private Handler handler = new Handler() {

                    /* (non-Javadoc)
                     * @see android.os.Handler#handleMessage(android.os.Message)
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                            setConnection(connection);
                    }

            };

            public void connect(final String username, final String password) {
                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                                                    "server ip", 5222, "localhost");
                                      connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);
                                    try {
                                            connection.connect();
                                    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                                            setConnection(null);
                                    } catch (SmackException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    try {
                                            connection.login(username, password);
                                    } catch (SaslException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (XMPPException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (SmackException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    handler.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(0, 1000);

                            }
                    });
                    t.start();
            }

    public void setConnection(XMPPTCPConnection connection) {
                    this.connection=connection;
                    if (connection != null) {
                    ....
```

Comment: Nothing changed.I am still getting same report for disconnect.

Comment: @Okan please check the updated answer regarding strictmode thread policy ... FYI http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/04/strictmodesetthreadpolicy-and.html

Comment: I don't want to use stritctmode is there an another way ? I tried your code but as i mentioned everything is same.

Comment: once can u pls call setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) in onPostExecute of async task instead of calling from public void connect(final String username,final String password) methid

Comment: @Okan issue with the thread policy only bcz its network related operation is gng on in main thread which will create issue for the above api 8

Comment: Also i put the setConnection to onPostExecute but still same.

Comment: check this http://pastebin.com/N4v487Xb...  assuming the internet permission is given in manifest

Comment: In first code,I didn't see anything different ? I am checking the second one now.

Comment: Thank you so much,the second one worked.But how ? Can you explain to me what was my fault ?

Comment: @Okan i have already tried to explain you about Thread policy..And even in you exception its also mentioning at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133) .. issue is with setConnection method

Comment: İ know it but i am asking why we used handler for this case ? I am curious about handler

Comment: @Okan create a Handler for a new thread, but you can also create a Handler that's connected to an existing thread. When you connect a Handler to your UI thread, the code that handles messages runs on the UI thread. Now if your problem is resolved thn dont forget to upvote

Comment: check thi like https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html#Handler

Comment: But now we are setting connection variable in ui thread. How disconnect is not giving network policy error ?

Comment: @Okan to disconnect with server wont required more process(like request for url , open connection , and all.After connecting with server jst need to disconnect the connection which is dne